# IIS modifies double slash to single slash in queryString

Tags: url, iis-7, http-status-code-404, httphandler

My problem is the following : 
I have a piece of code that acts as a gateway, routing the request to one back-end server or another. This code is actually implement in an IHttpHandler, which is triggered on a 404;

Pseudo code as follows :

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            var absoluteUri = context.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;

            //... clean URL to get the part that we need 

            string RedirectTo = ...;

            context.Response.Redirect(RedirectTo, false);                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

My problem is that in the queryString that reaches this code there are some parameters that are encrypted (and encoded).
Unfortunately, there wasn't much control on the way values are encrypted, and some values encrypted contains consecutive forward slashes.
ex: website/12345?params=o//go4lia0%3d

When IIS gets the request, the double slash is initially encoded (%3d%3d).

Logically, IIS doesn't find the corresponding document (which is expected) and calls the handler above. Problem is that at this stage, the query string has been decoded by IIS, and the 2 consecutive slashes transforms into a single one. Which results in a failure decrypting the query string.

Is there any way to tell IIS: please leave the double slashes alone ?

few clarifications: 
- this functionnality is to generate links that are sent to end-users so it populates automatically some field on the screen. I know it could be easier to handle that in an MVC controller... maybe I'll end up doing that instead of triggering a 404.

- the code that generates the encrypted values can be changed so that it does not generate slashes (which would have been a good idea in a first place, but there are already emails with incorrect links sent out, so it's kind of too late...

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you solved this problem? I don't know if you can tell IIS to leave double slashes alone, but you could parse the original untouched URL to get your unmodified query string values by accessing this server variable:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["UNENCODED_URL"]
```

I tried it, although double slashes disappear in HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl, they are still there in HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["UNENCODED_URL"].

Comment: Nope unfortunately this value gives me similar results as RawUrl or AbsoluteUri...
Thanks a lot anyway, I think I'm gonna try all ServerVariables, even though I'm pretty convinced that it's IIS that removes the double slash before the URL gets to the HttpHandler.

Comment: Actually I think I know what's wrong... The double slash is not in a query string in a first place, so that's why IIS gets rid of it, I should have noticed that earlier.

Comment: If it is not in the QueryString, I am not sure there is a solution. I had a similar problem to yours, so I used the UNENCODED_URL server variable as stated above, which resolved the problem. However, the links where this occurred were sent by email, and people using Outlook as mail client still had the problem, because Outlook cleans up URLs in emails, and is stripping double slashes. It is doing a bit too much actually.

Comment: I double checked and it's not in the Query String. Playing with IIS 7 logs, I found out that when the query hits IIS (so even before the 404 is triggered), the double slash is gone. This does not happen with a query string. Guess it's hopeless as it could be anything between IIS and the client so...